# revel Controller declaration syntax

Tags: go, revel

I am new to golang revel framework.

I have read revel tutorials and i see this lines at the top of each controller file:

```
type App struct {
    *revel.Controller
}
```

I suppose this mean my App class is derivated from Controller class.

Warning: i know the object model is not the same comparing to C++. I do not really think the word "derivated" are corrects in go...

My question is: What is the role of the asterix (*) before revel.Controller ?

Thanks

Comment: It's called embedding in go, i.e. `App` *embeds* `*revel.Controller`. A value of type `*T` is called a pointer to `T`. So in english that piece of code would translate into *"App embeds a pointer to revel.Controller"*. Before you try to learn a Go framework I would recommend you take the [Go Tour](https://tour.golang.org/welcome/1) to acquaint yourself with these basic Go concepts, otherwise your speed of learning that framework will be heavily impaired.

Comment: Golang has no classes, and no inheritance. Saying `App` is derived from `Controller` class is all shades of wrong. What you have there is called an embedded type, which means `App` is a struct that contains `Controller`, and allows for the exported `Controller` fields to be accessed directly (if no fields conflict). The asterisk means you need to initialise the `App` type with an embedded _pointer_ to `Controller`.  **Note: Revel is by many considered harmful**

Comment: Thanks for your answers. Why revel is considered harmul ? With which framework are you working ?

Comment: @Bob5421: Revel is harmful because it's trying to be an MVC framework. Golang wasn't intended to be used like that. Golang, as a language, is designed for small services that don't serve up fully templated pages. The templating bit is more commonly used for code generation than it is to render websites. TL;DR: most of the time, golang isn't used with a framework, but rather with packages like gorilla/mux and some stuff from go-kit. Not a full stack framework